# A problem on complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose p(z) is a polynomial of degree $n$ having no zeros in $|z|<1$ and $q(z)=z^n \overline{p(1/\overline{z})}$ then, is $|p(z)|<|q(z)|$ in |z|<1 true? May I know why?

Comment: It is always false. $|p(0)| \ge |q(0)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider $q(z)/p(z)$.  What do you know about it when $|z|=1$?

Comment: Thanks. |p(z)|=|q(z)| when |z|=1. I got the answer. Many many thanks to you.